# Google cloud storage correct image uploading

Tags: http, meteor, google-api, google-cloud-storage

Have a problem with correct image uploading. Text files uploading fine. Images uploading but when i open it from google storage then image dont display (even if i download it).

At frontend I'm getting file from computer and using FileReader() to convert file to binary. And on server I'm doing requests.

Code:

```
GoogleApi.prototype.uploadFile = function(file, cb) {
var token = this.token;
var privateInfo = Meteor.settings.private.GOOGLE;
console.log(file);                    //checked all info before sending. All is ok

try {
    var res = HTTP.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my_bucket_srohyi/o", {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": file.type,
            "Content-Length": file.size,
            Authorization: "Bearer" + " " + token
        },
        params: {
            project: privateInfo.project_id,
            uploadType: "media",
            name: file.name,

        },
        content: file.data        //using FileReader.readAsBinaryString()
    });
    return cb(null, res);
}
catch (err) {
    cb(err);
}
```

}

I'm working on meteor.js but i think it's not a meteor problem.
Hope someone can help me.
Also sorry if my english not good

Comment: I've always specified the `?uploadType=media` on uploads -- not sure what happens when you omit it, as you appear to have. Also, what code of yours is running on app engine? The JS you give appears to run in a browser, app engine not involved -- if so please remove the extraneous tag.

Comment: I have uploadType in code (params object), if you dont specify it, request will return an error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I hadn't noticed you were correctly specifying it, my bad.

Comment: Have you checked that "file.data" contains the correct value?

Comment: Yes, data is correct

Comment: Well, i resolved a problem with addition of quotation mark. Just needed to define 'content' key, not 'data'. But images still uploading bad. I will update post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved

Just need to transform a file in to array buffer (not in binary string) and create an Uint8Array from it.